# Force splice of ng-repeat array whilst using track by

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Our application has a list of tasks, which can grow quite large. The main tasks list has a sidebar, and when a task is selected, it can be edited in the sidebar - which uses a different controller (TasksSidebarCtrl rather than TasksCtrl that displays the list). The selected task is copied, and then merged back into the list. this communication is handled in **TasksService**.

The number of watchers per task in the index was huge, so we decided to take a different approach.

Using one time binding has greatly reduced to number of watchers (in fact, it's only the submenu to edit/change the status of a task without selecting it in the sidebar that creates watchers now), but because we are using **track by task.id** (which I see as a necessity considering the number of filters we have and how often the DOM will change), using splice does not remove and replace the task with the new updated task - which I understand is the whole point of track by.

**Is there a way to force to update of this task item whist still using both track by and one-time binding?**

**tasks-index.html** (I've removed the filters to aid readability)

```
<md-list-item my-task-directive ng-repeat="task in TasksCtrl.tasks track by task.id">
```

**TasksCtrl**

```
TasksService.index().then(function(tasks) {
    vm.tasks = tasks.data ? tasks.data : [];   
});

$scope.$on('task-updated', function() {
    var newTask = TasksService.getUpdatedTask();
    $timeout(function() {
        vm.tasks.splice(newTask.index, 1, newTask.task);
    });
});
```

**TaskSidebarCtrl**

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return TasksService.getSelectedTask();
}, function (newVal, oldVal) {

    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        /* Using copy here so index view does not update as we edit */
        vm.selectedTask = angular.copy(newVal);
        vm.index = TasksService.getSelectedTaskIndex();

    }
});

TasksService.update(vm.selectedTask).then(function(data) {
    // notifications etc here, then...
    TasksService.updateTaskInIndex(vm.index, data.data);
});
```

**TasksService**

```
var selectedTask = {};
var indexOfTask;
var updatedTask = {};
var updatedIndex;

this.setSelectedTask = function(task, index) {
    selectedTask = task;
    indexOfTask = index;
};
this.getSelectedTask = function() {
    return selectedTask;
};
this.getSelectedTaskIndex = function() {
    return indexOfTask;
};
this.getUpdatedTask = function() {
        return {
            'index': updatedIndex,
            'task': updatedTask
        };
};
this.updateTaskInIndex = function(index, task) {
    updatedTask = task;
    updatedIndex = index;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('task-updated');
};
```

Using a simple angular.copy (with destination) instead of **TasksService.updateTaskInIndex(vm.index, data.data)** in the TaskSidebarCtrl **update** function means that the one-time bound properties are not updated in the index view because of the one time binding. The above works without **track by task.id** but I do't want to make this sacrifice if possible. Nor do I want to sacrifice the one-time binding.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: Excellent question. Do you have some plunker with a example?

Comment: Tried replicating the issue. It worked fine http://jsfiddle.net/21Lt4g26/

Comment: @rishabhdev you're not using one time binding - hence it works. Using one time binding is imperative due to the complexity of my task objects and the number that need to be rendered

Comment: what do you mean by one time binding. Can you please edit the fiddle to show? @CIvemy

Comment: @rishabhdev http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2014/10/14/exploring-angular-1.3-one-time-bindings.html

Comment: How about changing the id when the task is updated? 
Also, if you had a performance issue, the problem might not have been the large number of watchers but the DOM manipulation caused by the filters in the ng-repeat. Try moving them to ng-show to only hide items, not remove them to speed things up.

Comment: @yscik I don't fancy that. Change to what? Can't risk a conflict

Comment: @CIvemy You could use something like id_version in a new property for tracking, combining the id and a version increased on every edit.

Comment: @yscik that's an interesting idea, thanks for that. However, say I have 2 tasks, one has id of 1, which I edited twice, so tracking_id = 3, then I edit another task with id 2 once, it will have a duplicate tracking_id

Comment: @CIvemy The values of track by expressions doesnt have to be numeric, what i meant was to have a tracking id formatted as `"{id}_{version}"`. You have a non-changing `id` property, and a separate `version` for every object.

Comment: @yscik that was a great idea. If you put that in an answer I'll mark as correct - thanks for your help! Rather than run two queries when storing a new task (one to store, another to use the newly created auto inc ID to build the version value), I initially store a microtime timestamp . '_0', then convert to the ID , '_1' on first update

Comment: Posted it with a proper explanation, glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `track by task.id` gets the same value for the new updated task, it won't rebuild the DOM elements for the entry, and the expressions in this existing element wont update due to one-time binding.

Using a `track by` expressions that changes when the entry is updated will remove the old task's node and insert a new one, where the one-time bound expressions will be evaluated again. A simple way for this is to assign the task a `tracking_id` property with an `"{id}_{version}"` format, where version changes with every update, and use `track by task.tracking_id`.